# How to disable select box border in IE-6 browser

Tags: html

```
select
{
border:none;
}

<select>
<otpion value='male'>Male</option>
<otpion value='female'>Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS property `outline: none;`

Although this is sometimes frowned upon as it can make your site difficult to use with the keyboard (when you use tab to shift through elements, no outline will appear).

Comment: I want to disable the border line